# Bypass Load Balancer using .NET

Tags: .net, load-balancing

I have a web service which I need to invoke after every deployment. It is deployed on around 10 servers. Right now I invoke the service one after one on each server by modifying the host file. This works fine for me.

But, I want to automate this process of invoking the service using .NET code. Is there any way this can be done through code. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you mention bypassing load balancer in the title? What particular operations do you need to do post deployment?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how the servers are configured.  I typically keep a unique addressable URL available for each node within a farm.  For example server1.mysite.net and server2.mysite.net.

If you have this situation setup then you could easily have a post deploy process using a simple app that just iterated through to make a call to each endpoint.